# How to limit the number of elements returned by Stream API expression

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am using the expression below, to achieve the following:

Between Product objects with the same `name::String`, extract the Product that has the highest `weight::BigDecimal` value.

I would like to limit the length of the returned Collection by adding to this expression, but I am not sure how this could be done - specifically, I want to populate the list with up to 3 Product objects, ideally, the heaviest ones.

```
Collection<Product> heaviestProductsDistinct = products.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName, b -> b,
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice))))
    .values();
```

For example, lets say I have:

```
List<Product> products = List.of(
        new Product("product1", BigDecimal.valueOf(3), "valid"),
        new Product("product1", BigDecimal.valueOf(2), "expired"),
        new Product("product1", BigDecimal.valueOf(5), "expired"),

        new Product("product2", BigDecimal.valueOf(4), "valid"),
        new Product("product2", BigDecimal.valueOf(10), "valid"),

        new Product("product3", BigDecimal.valueOf(9), "expired"),
        new Product("product3", BigDecimal.valueOf(3)), "valid",

        new Product("product4", BigDecimal.valueOf(12), "valid"),
        new Product("product4", BigDecimal.valueOf(33), "valid")
);
```

My expression will return:

```
[Product{name='product4', price=33, condition='valid'}, Product{name='product2', price=10, condition='valid'}, 
Product{name='product1', price=5, condition='expired'}, Product{name='product3', price=9, condition='valid'}]
```

From that, I would like to keep only two elements, ideally the ones with the highest price.

Comment: Which “returned `ArrayList`” are you talking about? There is no `ArrayList` in your code. And why do you say “I want to populate the list with up to 3 Product objects” and then, later “I would like to keep only two elements”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is unclear, so here are two

**Most expensive 3 products, where only the most expensive for each name is chosen**

```
final List<Product> collect = products.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Product::getName,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice))
        )
    )
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice).reversed())
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Most expensive 3 products for each name**

You can first group by name, then use `collectingAndThen` to take the resulting list for each name, sort it, and get the top 3.

This will give you a map. Then you can iterate and join all the values if you want.

```
List<Product> collect = products.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Product::getName,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice).reversed())
                    .limit(3)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
        )
    ) // here you have a Map<String, List<Product>>
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but it does not return Products that have distinct name.
First, if I have 3 Product objects with the same name, I keep only the one with the highest weight. So the code that I have posted returns a Collection, of Product objects with unique name, that each is also the heaviest Product of that name. But from this returned collection, I would like to be abe to keep only N number of results.

Comment: Yes, and then from them, to be able to keep only N number of them

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of the question. I added a detailed example.
And the first part of your post, is the one that answers my question. Thank you!
(Most expensive 3 products, where only the most expensive for each name is chosen)

Comment: Why did you change the OP’s code from `Collectors.toMap(…)` to `Collectors.groupingBy(… Collectors.maxBy(…))`? All you gained, was the necessity to insert `.filter(Optional::isPresent) .map(Optional::get)` afterwards.

Comment: @Holger, could you please post the complete expression?

Comment: @Holger I didn't pay any attention to what they already had. From Java 9, it's a choice between an extra identity function in `toMap` and `flatMap(Optional::stream)` (I didn't use that version, since it was tagged as Java 8). I think `groupingBy` better conveys the intent but the difference is irrelevant

Comment: @Michael, thank you for sticking with Java-8, as using this version is a requirement for my code.